# How to change a link on refresh?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a select box behaviour but using list items.

So far I have create the select box here: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/4ASft/9/

So I open Dates - then I would select Date1 - the page would need to refresh - so the main Dates link would change to Date1.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: did not get the part about page refresh. please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').click(function() {
        var listItem = this;
        $('.activate_modal').html($(listItem).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the:

> the page would need to refresh

But the rest can be done with this:

```
    $('ul').each(function() {
        $(this).find('li').click(function() {
            var listItem = this;
            $('.activate_modal').text($(listItem).text());
            close_modal();
        });
    });
```